# Lecture videos for learning algebraic curves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, soft-question, algebraic-curves, affine-varieties

I am an MSc.final year student of Mathematics.In the $4^{\text {th}}$ semester of our MSc. programme,a student has to take a reading project on some topic and present the same in front of the department.I have taken a project on Algebraic curves and I am reading the book *Algebraic Curves: An Introduction to Algebraic Geometry-Fulton*.But it is very difficult to get a flavour of such an advanced topic only by reading a book.So,I am looking for a good lecture series that covers at least the first $5$ chapters of Fulton viz.

$1.$ Affine Algebraic sets.

$2.$ Affine Varieties.

$3.$ Local properties of Plane curves.

$4.$ Projective Varieties.

$5.$ Projective plane curves.

Can someone suggest me some good lecture videos covering these topics so that I can enter the topic properly and build a good project?

Comment: There are Borcherd's Algebraic Geometry lecture videos online which are useful and cover a lot of what you're interested in. In particular, the first set of lectures on algebraic varieties.

Comment: @AHappyMathematician The lecture series you are mentioning is okay for an overview,but I was looking for rigorous course....

Comment: In that case, there is always Miles Reid's Lecture Series on Basic Algebraic Geometry. The video quality isn't the best, but it is still legible.